# Vaadin 7 don't refresh UI after execution background thread (only if it takes more than 5 minutes)

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 7. In my application there's a table list and user could choice one or more items to elaborate. If execute button is clicked, UI component are disabled and two Threads start: 
1st Thread does heavy computation 
2nd Thread updating progress indicator on UI (with lock() and unlock() method)

At the end 1st Thread:

item is deleted from DB, all component removed and re-added (enabled). In this way refreshing table data is assured.

It works well, but when a long task is processed UI doesn't refresh and table are disabled yet.

Anybody could help me?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/231272

In short - in Vaadin 6.0 and 7.0, you cannot "push" a change from the server to the browser from a non-request thread. (There are plugins for v6, but not for v7.0)

In Vaadin 7.1 (not yet released) this is possible. See https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Enabling+server+push for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.                                               I really don't understand why it occurs ONLY if thread takes more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @user2312187 Sorry, I didn't see the Progress Indicator note; using  Progress Indicator means that the client side will be updated. I imagine that 5 minutes is related to the Vaadin 7 Heartbeat (https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.ui-expiration) - but more than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you explain me how works heartbeatInterval? I set in web.xml, for example: <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
   <param-value>3600</param-value>                                                  and then? I've just tried with this conf: all the component are disable, without only the table remains disabled.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't : I'm fairly new to Vaadin 7. Might I suggest you direct your questions to the Vaadin forum http://vaadin.com/forum , where more knowledgeable people might be able to help.

Comment: I tried for a week but I can't post because vaadin forum site reply: It seems something wrong with DB...

Comment: @user2312187 : Vaadin Forum appears to be working fine (last post was just 2 minutes ago at 13:45 UTC on 07 May 2013)

Comment: This problem is showed only when I try to open a new thread in forum section!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a component which refreshes periodically like the ProgressIndicator. Disable it after the thread has finished. That works for me.