# How to execute JavaScript on the client side with a timer in Vaadin?

Tags: javascript, java, timer, vaadin

I want to move a component of my Vaadin Portlet every 5 seconds.
I tried starting a java timer and also a javascript timer via

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(...);
```

but it did not work.
Is there any way to do this with Vaadin?
An example would be greatly appreciated.

I want to move the component by manipulating how far away from the left it is positioned. The first call of the timer (setInterval(progressTimeline, 3000)) works, but after that it does not do anything.

Comment: How do you plan to move it? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: @default Edited my question.

Comment: You need some kind of polling/pushing mechanism to notify client-side on changes made by Timer. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301476/vaadin-7-dont-refresh-ui-after-execution-background-thread-only-if-it-takes-mo

Comment: @default so there is no way to do this completely on the client side? I want to do this every five seconds or so and dont really want to communicate with the server every time..